# connecting bluetooth device with mobile app

Tags: android

I have three bluetooth devices which works with one app. These are health devices-blood pressure monitor, weighing scale and activity tracker. I am also using a fourth device which is working with a different app. Is it possible that the fourth device can be integrated with the first app? If it is possible, what needs to be done to integrate the fourth device with the other app. I request you to answer it in layman language which is easily understandable.

Waiting for the reply.

Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Android `BluetoothSocket` class allows us to transfer data between Android to any devices which have Bluetooth felicity.

1)Establish connection with the device using [Blueetoth](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

2)Get `OutputStream` for writing data into device and `inputstream` for reading data from the device Using `BluetoothSocket`class after establishing the connection

You can find example here https://github.com/simonguest/android-btxfr